# disable validation with click yup schema

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form, yup

How can I make it so that after clicking on the input the 'yup' doesn't add a validation?

[Demonstration](https://i.imgur.com/8eAWQNb.mp4)

```
const signInFormSchema = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup.string().required("Required email").email("Invalid email"),
  password: yup.string().required("Password required"),
});
```

Comment: To better help, you could you please provide more information? Such as eventual form packages used (Formik?) and the rest of the Form-code with event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Formik you just need to set validateOnBlur to false

https://formik.org/docs/api/withFormik#validateonblur-boolean